# how can I change a string from ANSI to UTF8 in Javascript? the binary code needs to change

Tags: javascript, json, utf-8

I have a  tag where the user can input text, but it happened that when copying text that's not encoded in utf8 I get a different output when sending the data in a Json file. look at this=>

I made this code to test the problem=>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
<input id="q1">
<input id="q2">
</form>
<button onclick="as()">calcular</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function as(){
var w=document.getElementById("q1").value;
var z=document.getElementById("q2").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode( new TextEncoder('windows-1252').encode(w));
    var binaryA1=new TextEncoder('windows-1252').encode(w);
    var binaryA2=new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(binaryA1);
    var binaryA3=new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode(binaryA2);
    var binaryB1=unescape(encodeURIComponent(w));
    var binaryB2=decodeURIComponent(escape(binaryB1));//binaryB1.replace("Â","");
    var binaryB3=new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode(binaryB2);
    var binaryC1=new TextEncoder('windows-1252').encode(z);
    debugger;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have two inputs, in the first input (w) I pasted a string from a ANSI file, on the second input (z) I just wrote the same text on the input, so it'd be in UTF-8. what I need is the first input (w) to end up with the same binaries as the second input (z) and by comparing the binary we can see that it's almost identical except for the 11th position of the array, in binaryC1 (z) we have 32 but on the other binaries (w) we have 194 and 160 (so two positions) is there a way that I can do this for all strings? I don't want to hard code a correction.

```
memory=>
binaryA1: Uint8Array(17) [83, 111, 109, 101, 116, 104, 105, 110, 103, 111, 114, 194, 160, 73, 107, 111, 114]

binaryA2: "Somethingor Ikor"

binaryA3: Uint8Array(17) [83, 111, 109, 101, 116, 104, 105, 110, 103, 111, 114, 194, 160, 73, 107, 111, 114]

binaryB1: "SomethingorÂ Ikor"

binaryB2: "Somethingor Ikor"

binaryB3: Uint8Array(17) [83, 111, 109, 101, 116, 104, 105, 110, 103, 111, 114, 194, 160, 73, 107, 111, 114]

binaryC1: Uint8Array(16) [83, 111, 109, 101, 116, 104, 105, 110, 103, 111, 114, 32, 73, 107, 111, 114]
```

Comment: What was the original problem exactly?  All this encoding and decoding with binary arrays doesn't seem to have much to do with saving to JSON. And what code was used to do that saving? And what was used to view the data afterwards?

Comment: P.S. You don't have inputs w and z in your code, so the description is a bit hard to follow and relate to the code.

Comment: the input is in my code, see in the example where it says binaryB1? that's what the user copied and pasted, and that binaryB3, that's the binary data of that same string. if that same user was to write the same word it would have ended up with the binary data of  binaryC1. same word, different binary data. when I send that to my rest API it's decoded with that Â that ruins everything. I need that thing to disapear, and replace doesn't work for that.

Comment: [`TextEncoder`](https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-textencoder) ignores the encoding argument given to it, and always encodes strings as UTF-8. (Historically, this wasn’t the case.)

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that

Comment: Ok  but sending stuff to the server would be done in plain text. It's unclear where the binary would come into it in the real-world code? Or how it relates to JSON? You still didn't explain the real-world scenario. Are you using TextEncoder for real in your application where you've been having this issue?

Comment: ok, so I have a Java API Rest service, that is called from AngularJs front. The user inputs the string that will be send with the Json formatted body HTTP POST, if you look at the string you will not see the Â, but once I check the HTTP POST at the browser network tab, I can see it there. I used the Decoder to see the difference at the binary data level, because the strings look the same but the binaries are different. I've tried doing replace to eliminate that, but I looked at the binary data of the string and that replace didn't fix the problem.

Comment: `194, 160` is the UTF-8 encoding of U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE, `32` is an ordinary space.

Comment: thank you very much, that's a really helpful, I can work with that